# Understanding @Transactional when table used as a Queue

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I have a table which looks something like the following:

```
id | task | status
--------------------------
1  | xxxx | done
2  | xxxx | in_progress
3  | xxxx | in_progress
4  | xxxx | in_progress
5  | xxxx | todo
```

we have handlers which are built in spring-boot/JPA.

The first handler pulls a few records(which are in todo) from the above table and marks them as in_progress.

a second handler then pulls a few more records(which are in todo) from the above table and marks them as in_progress.

a second handler could potentially pull todo records even when the first handler hasn't completed marking them as in_progress.

I have used Transaction for all or nothing approach.

would a `@Transactional` annotation(or transactions) solve such an issue? if not what are the ways in which this could be tackled using Spring/JPA (and not using an external Queue).

Comment: Transactional only for acid db operations, but not solve concurrency issues. You can use optimistic/pessimistic lock. But if all the handler just pull and mark, then the result is same. It will do data process between them? Please give some more information: What  problem do you want to solve? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Where on Earth do people get the idea that transactions are not there to solve concurrency issues? What's the point of *I* in *ACID* if not concurrency control? Yes, of course you can use `@Transactional`, provided that you are willing to set transaction isolation level of your transaction to `SERIALIZABLE`, since you'll want a range lock for the `status = todo` query